# New to HTML and need advice

Tags: html, wordpress, finance

I want to build a financial management website for a company. I want to create inputs where the user can add information and then they can see a summary of their data along with a graph, and also be able to do forecasts.

Honestly, I have no idea where to start on this. I'm new to HTML, but I've done a few tutorials and I've worked with C# in the past. I just bought a website domain and I have installed Wordpress.

Any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This site is for specific programming questions; this is too broad.  Please see the introductory tour for guidance on [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

I am beginner just like you.I see that you need frontend(client side) and backend(database).My opinion is to try learn this 5 first:HTML,CSS,JavaScript,MySql,PHP.After that you will have better vision what you can do.Good learning resourses are:
https://www.codecademy.com/learn
https://www.bento.io/
html5rocks
css-tricks
sqlzoo.net/
Google it,learn and work hard.Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner too.
Here you've got my advices:

1. Try to start to understand how HTML works. (You need to know that HTML never acts at the server.
   After you study tables, divs and some CSS (image is very important).
   Its time to start studying PHP.
   With a very low level of PHP (knowing how variables work) and all HTML you've learnt before, you will be able to create a simple webpage that contains a sign up.
   Now its time to introduce that data in some place.
   Where will you do it?
   Thats right, you will do it in a MYSQL database.
   So for a perfect server you need ---> HTML+CSS+PHP+MYSQL+attitude

P.S. I recomend you to buy a rapberry pi and install APACHE server and MYSQL on it so you can fight face to face with HTML, CSS and PHP without useing Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to input data, you can use a `<form>` tag. Here's an example:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <input type="submit" id="sub">
</form>
```

If you want the data to be displayed to the user through the website, you can use `document.getElementById("body tag id here").innerHTML = "data here"`.